# How do tag preferences work in Review?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review

On Stackoverflow when I click on review and select "First posts", it starts showing me posts. **Is it showing me posts having my favourite tags?**

If **Yes**, then it's good but bad too. Here is something what I want to say:

*I means "User who is reviewing the posts" and system means "The Stackoverflow Engine" in my example.*

Let's assume I have two favourite tags, Ruby-On-Rails and Android. By profession I am a Ruby-on-Rails developer and I am learning Android and I want to monitor questions related to Android too, so I added into my favorites.

But I don't want to review Android questions coming on Stackoverflow in the review section. The only reason behind this is I am not capable enough to proof read them. I am a learner in Android so why is the system asking me to review those posts? So I keep clicking on "not sure" again and again.

It would be great if the system could copy my list of favorite tags and then in the review section I can manually remove the ones I don't feel comfortable reviewing, in order to explain to the system that it should only show me questions to review for these specific tags.

Review Suggested Edits sometimes don't require language expertise, but it can good be to have a option to stop geting those posts.

*PS: I know learning is a constant process. But working for the past 2 years in Ruby-on-Rails makes me comfortable to review those posts, but for Android it's just barely 2 weeks. So please don't say anything about that in answers.*

[image]

Comment: If the proffered review question is outside your area of expertise, hitting the 'Not Sure' button doesn't take long (and possibly less time than deselecting the favourites that you're unwilling to pontificate on).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think you missed the whole point of the question. Suppose there are some 100 posts of ruby on rails and 100 for android, while reviews 100 times i need to click on "not sure". I am saying don't show me those 100 posts.

Comment: I understand that. I subscribe to quite a large number of tags and some of those are ones that I won't usually pontificate on, and I use 'Not Sure' frequently.  I am not saying that it is bad idea; I'm saying it is not unbearable as it is.  It would depend in part on whether the system goes through your preferred tags in any sort of systematic order; 100 Android questions before any RoR ones would annoy me in your shoes, but I don't see that happening with the tags I'm subscribed to.  And it depends whether the tags to review are recorded once for ever (editable, of course) or per-session.

Comment: The default behavior will most likely continue to infer tag preferences based on your favorites, but we will soon roll out a power-userish feature whereby you can filter review queues by post type, tag, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Review feature already takes your favorite/ignored into consideration when choosing posts for you to review. In addition, your *inferred* tag preferences (based on your behavior on the site) are considered as well.

We just rolled out a new feature which lets you manually select the tags you'd like to see in review. To filter a review queue by tag, you can now click the "filter" link beside the heading and select up to 3 tags.

Comment: Awesome. This is exactly I was looking for :)